# Возврат во фрагмент из Активити

Tags: android

У меня во фрагменте по интервалу отправляется запрос на сервер, каждый 20 секунд. Получая новые данные я обновляю recyclerview адаптер. Из каждой позиции я могу переходить в активити для подробной информации. Как сделать, что бы при переходе в активити интервал запросов во фрагменте останавливался, а после нажатие кнопки назад возобновлялся?
вот код таймера.

```
private void timer() {
    timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            URL url = generateForId(sources.get(position).getCompanyId() + "/sources/request-status");
            new AsyncTimer().execute(url);
        }
    };

    timer.schedule(timerTask, 0, 20000);

}
```

при переходе в активити таймер останавливаю.

```
timer.cancel();
```

Comment: смею предположить что вы можете использовать методы жизненного цикла фрагмента. В onResume запускать в onPause останавливать.

Comment: – Eugene Zaychenko. Спасибо, получилось.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cмею предположить что вы можете использовать методы жизненного цикла фрагмента. В onResume запускать в onPause останавливать.